# How to convert a text name format to excel date?

Tags: excel

I have a column that has a name date: **Friday, December 25, 2015**
and I want to convert it to a date format: **12/25/2015** , that way I can perform other date functions.

I have unsuccessfully tried both changing the format directly and using the =DATEVAL() function.

Any direction would be great. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First remove the day names

Ctrl+f and just replace "Friday," or "Saturday," or other days with ""
now your columns should be formatted like
"December 25, 2015"

Now use the dateval function like
=DATEVALUE("December 25, 2015")

Now select date from formatting and you should be good.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am dumbfounded as to why I didnt remove the additional Weekday (Friday or Saturday) to begin with. Thanks for your help and I too will be coming back and repping you once I get above the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

With text in **A1** use:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1,1)+2,9999))
```

and format as a *Date*:

[image]